# Why is R getting the same index for the same values?

Tags: r, indexing

I think it's quite simple but I need to ask: why the index of the diario variable is always the same for the value 10 in this vector?

Below, you can see that the value 10 always has the index 1, meanwhile, negative numbers, which are different from each other, have different index.

> match(diario,diario)
>    [1]  1  1  3  1  5  1  1  1  9  1 11  1  1  1 15  1  1  1 19  1
>
> diario
>    [1]  10  10  -9  10 -15  10  10  10 -27  10 -33  10  10  10 -45  10  10  10 -57  10

Isn't it weird? I was expecting different index for the value 10.

```
diario <- 0
for(i in 1:20)
{
  check <- sample(1:2,1)
  if(check == 1)
  {
    diario[i] <- 10
  }
  if(check == 2)
  {
    diario[i] <- -i*3
  }
}
match(diario,diario)
diario
```

Comment: The `match()` function returns the first matching index for each value. Since your `diario` has a 10 in the first slot, all 10's will be matched with the first index. What behavior where you expecting exactly? There's no way to tell "which 10 is which". They all are just "10".

Comment: match always returns the position of thefirst match. Since a 10 is the first element of your vector every 10 will always return the position 1.

Comment: @MrFlick, it would be really important to know exactly what index I was looking for. Is there anything else I can do?